# #VALUE! error when calling UDF function on worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function that will calculate the Total quantity of a product with number "pn001" and minus the sum in another sheet, the answer should be displayed in sheet where the function is called

```
Function salio() As Long

    Dim Sumact As Range
    Dim Sumact1 As Range
    Dim Remain As Long
    Dim RR As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Set Sumact = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Set Sumact1 = Sheets("SALES").Range("A1")
    Sheets("STOCK-OUT").Select
    Sumact = Application.SumIf(Range("C3:C5"), "pn001", Range("E3:E5"))
    RR = CLng(Sumact)
    Sheets("SALES").Select
    Sumact1 = Application.SumIf(Range("D2:D5"), "pn001", Range("F2:F5"))
    Remain = CLng(Sumact1)
    R = RR - Remain
    salio = R
End Function
```

All I get is the #VALUE! error when I attempt to use this on a worksheet.

Comment: **What is your question??**  You already have some code.  Does it work??

Comment: Do you really need a UDF to do this? Your code is just imitating what Excel's native formulas can already do. Surely you can accomplish this without any VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this code in a *Module* code sheet and not a worksheet code sheet, then I suspect that your problems have to do with using `.Select` in function. The Select method can be used in macro Subs, but you cannot be switching around worksheets in a function to be used on a worksheet. You also cannot put values into any other cells that the one that the UDF function resides in.

```
Function salio() As Long
    'Dim Sumact As Range   you cannot set these to a range to receive a sumif
    'Dim Sumact1 As Range   you cannot set these to a range to receive a sumif
    Dim Sumact As Long
    Dim Sumact1 As Long
    Dim Remain As Long
    Dim RR As Long
    Dim R As Long

    'Set Sumact = Sheets(1).Range("A1")   you cannot set these to a range to receive a sumif
    'Set Sumact1 = Sheets("SALES").Range("A1")   you cannot set these to a range to receive a sumif
    With Sheets("STOCK-OUT")  'do not .Select - Use With ... End With to reference another worksheet
        Sumact = Application.SumIf(.Range("C3:C5"), "pn001", .Range("E3:E5"))
    End With
    RR = CLng(Sumact)
    With Sheets("SALES")  'do not .Select - Use With ... End With to reference another worksheet
        Sumact1 = Application.SumIf(.Range("D2:D5"), "pn001", .Range("F2:F5"))
    End With
    Remain = CLng(Sumact1)
    R = RR - Remain
    salio = R
End Function
```

I've left some dead code in there as well as several comments. You will also want to review [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).